# Null Reference Exception with Datagridview Win Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I am stuck with one of the Issue in DataGridView of WinForms.
The DataGridView has 3 columns, One is hidden and the Last column shows up as a Progress bar.
The Rows are added into the DataGridView after every 1 minute using Timer.

**Issue**

An unhandled exception is raised in the Application which seems like is not raised by my Code.
On high level it seems like while adding rows into the DataGridview, paint is getting Invoked and which throws the exception. (Just my assumption)
Also this exception comes sometimes and not reproducible everytime.
With this exception a red cross appears on the DataGridView.

**Code**

```
    try
        {
            dgvRunProgress.Rows.Clear();
            var topLeftHeaderCell = dgvRunProgress.TopLeftHeaderCell;
            if (topLeftHeaderCell != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in lstForGrid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var status = item.HasError ? Convert.ToString(ProgressBarStatus.Error) : Convert.ToString(ProgressBarStatus.Completed);
                        if (dgvRunProgress != null && dgvRunProgress.Rows != null)
                            dgvRunProgress.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.RunID, item.ExtractNameWithId.Trim(), $"{item.ProgressValue}-{status}" });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.writeLog(LogType.ERROR, "BindRunProgressGrid Inner: " + ex.ToString());
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        dgvRunProgress.Update();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if (vScrollBar1.Height > (lstForGrid.Count() + 1) * 25 - 2)
            {
                dgvRunProgress.Height = vScrollBar1.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                dgvRunProgress.Height = (lstForGrid.Count() + 1) * 25 - 2;
            }

            //DataGridViewSelectionMode oldmode = dgvRunProgress.SelectionMode;
            //dgvRunProgress.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            //dgvRunProgress.ClearSelection();
            //dgvRunProgress.SelectionMode = oldmode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.writeLog(LogType.ERROR, "BindRunProgressGrid Outer: " + ex.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            dgvRunProgress.Update();
        }
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: please add code using the editor, don't paste screenshots of your code.

Comment: Added code for better visibility